# Is it possible to integrate angular.js and ember.js in the same page?

Tags: angularjs, ember.js

Is it possible to use both angular js and ember js inside a single div element in a single web page?

Is it not recommended (best practice)?

Comment: That really does not seem like a good idea. What are you trying to accomplish? _Why_ do you want to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  I don't see why you'd want to do it, but you didn't mention the use case, so I can't say it is or isn't recommended for your situation.